Waiting for element to rererender
Take this piece of code:
document.querySelector(":root").style.setProperty("--image-size", "100px");
console.log(document.querySelector("#item").offsetHeight);

And this stylesheet:
:root {
  --image-size: 10px;
}

#item {
  width: var(--image-size);
}

The output of the javascript code will be 19. What I was expecting is 190.
This is because the element hasn't rerendered yet. I have found another issue where the solution was to wait for one animation frame. Updated code looks like this:
document.querySelector(":root").style.setProperty("--image-size", "100px");
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
 requestAnimationFrame(() => {
   console.log(document.querySelector("#item").offsetHeight);
  }):
});

This still outputs 19. Am I missing something here? How can I wait for the element to rerender in this case?

Please add code here , so we can able to help you

Not reproducible, reading offsetWidth or offsetHeight forces layout recalculation in the middle of the script execution. See Layout thrashing.

If you show your HTML, perhaps it would be immediately clear that you're using an img tag perhaps (image loaded dynamically)? Anyways, create a [mcve].

what about using setTimeout(() => { console.log...; }) ?

Maybe you can force the browser to perform a reflow (layout recalculation) by accessing properties like offsetHeight or clientHeight. This should be used with caution since it can cause performance issues.


document.querySelector(":root").style.setProperty("--image-size", "100px");

// Force a reflow by accessing offsetHeight or another reflow-triggering property
document.querySelector("#item").offsetHeight;

requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  console.log(document.querySelector("#item").offsetHeight); // Should reflect the correct height
});
:root {
  --image-size: 10px;
}

#item {
  width: var(--image-size);
  height: var(--image-size);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: lightblue; /* To make the element visible */
}
<div id="item">
  ITEM
</div>



Notice box-sizing property which is important to calculate width and height properly.
Let me know if you need further assistance.

Why would this make a difference? OP already accesses offsetHeight in console.log's argument, that's where the layout is recalculated, and then the newly calculated value is logged.

@Teemu OP expected offsetHeight value to change upon accessing it the first time, they were not triggering a reflow, or at least not correctly. This answer shows how to perform the reflow first.

@silvenon Accessing offsetHeight before logging it is redundant (reading it in the argument will cause recalculation as well, before the result is logged to the console), the code would log the same result without the extra access too. Like I said, "not reproducible".

@Teemu indeed, OP is not reproducible and doesn't offer enough context, and accessing offsetHeight twice with requestAnimationFrame callback in between the two calls results in layout thrashing. I spent a lot of time in CSS transition land, so I forgot that triggering a reflow is not necessary to get the current offsetHeight.
